# Firebase Cloud Messaging No of Topics Topic Limit?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a limit on the no of topics there can be for users to subscribe per app?

As per https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging,

> Topic messaging supports unlimited subscriptions for each topic. However, FCM enforces limits in these areas: One app instance can be subscribed to no more than 2000 topics.

Does this mean we can have an maximum of 2000 topics per project? If not what does App instance mean?

NB: I found a similar question but its from 2016 and outdated since firebase have changed a lot since then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean we can have an maximum of 2000 topics per app?

You can have 2000 topic **subscriptions** per app instance.  Otherwise, you can have as many topics as you want, disregarding what individual app instances might expect from them.

> what does App instance mean?

An app instance is a unique installation of an app, separate from other installations of the same app on other devices.